# Why didn't Ms Delphox use Teller to melt the guilty brain of The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

In the [*Time Heist*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Heist) episode of *Doctor Who* (2014) season 8, Teller caught The Doctor and Clara in the vault and took them to Ms Delphox's office. As to why didn't Teller finish them there in the vault, it's possible that Ms Delphox wanted to ask few questions to the first vault breaker in the history ([Teller was mentally linked with her](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68199/931)).

But, after Ms Delphox interrogated The Doctor, why did she tell guards to kill (which would be painless) The Doctor and Clara? Why didn't she tell Teller to melt The Doctor's brain? After all, he was guilty of biggest crime of all.

Comment: related, not dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82144/why-doesnt-the-teller-pick-up-on-saibra-and-psi

Answer (score 5):

I suspect because they were in private. Note that when we saw the brain-melting previously, it was right out in the open where it could be witnessed. It was a very clear threat and warning meant not for the person being melted but for the people around them. "Watch yourself or this could be you."

In the absence of an audience, there was no need for such a gaudy show. Quicker and easier to just kill them and be done with it.

Comment: And the solar flare was about to fry the bank anyway, so a quick execution would be better.

Comment: She does seem to be the pragmatic type.

Comment: @tilley31 She didn't know that solar flare was going to fry the bank.

Answer (score 3):

Because the Teller was tired. Note that MS Delphox's [next action](http://issuu.com/berkeguzel/docs/ep_5) was to take it back into its hibernation pod.

> **The Doctor :** (Reading her perfectly) *You're scared.*
>
> **MS DELPHOX :** *I’m terrified. I have the disadvantage of knowing Karabraxos personally*.
>
> **THE DOCTOR :** *If you don't like your boss, why stay?*
>
> **MS DELPHOX** : (A cynical smile) *My face fits . **Now, if you’ll excuse me, I must take the Teller to its hibernation.***    (to
>   Guards) *You two, dispose of our guests.*
>
> And she leaves with the TELLER in tow.

Comment: Where does the transcript say that the Teller was tired?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - Because he's being lead back into hibernation. Also, he looks very tired.

Comment: 1. Don't go in reverse. 2. Haha.. How exactly did perceive that rare species with strange face tired?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - He was moving far slower, his gait was shuffling and his head was bowed. That = tired.

Comment: Don't compare with human behavior...